# Magento 2 - How to override block template

Tags: php, magento2, magento-2.0

I try to override

> vendor\magento\module-multishipping\view\frontend\templates\checkout\addresses.phtml

I create the layout

> app\code\My\CustomModule\view\frontend\layout\multishipping_checkout_addresses.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Multishipping\Block\Checkout\Addresses" name="checkout_addresses" template="My_CustomModule::checkout/addresses.phtml" cacheable="false">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

And the template

> app\code\My\CustomModule\view\frontend\templates\checkout\addresses.phtml

```
<h1>It works </h1>
```

It doesn't work... Please help me!
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<referenceBlock name='copyright'>
    <action method='setTemplate'>
        <argument name='template' xsi:type='string'>Dfr_Backend::page/copyright.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: What is "Dfr_Backend" and why is that in EVERY example of how to change a template but it's NEVER explained?  Is that a custom module?  What if I want to override a template in my theme but I don't have a custom module, where do I put it then and what's the syntax?

Comment: `Dfr_Backend` is a custom module which contains the new (custom) template. You should specify your module name instead of `Dfr_Backend`.

Comment: why you change the name of the example. it's easier if you put the answer based on the example

Answer (score 2):

The `<action>` instruction is deprecated. You can also use:

```
<referenceBlock name="form.subscribe" template="{Vendor_Module}::newsletter/subscribe.phtml" />
```